# Oracle Enterprise vs Express returns different results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have encountered strange problem.

We search from `2015-07-11` to `2015-07-13` (example situation)

In enterprise edition `07-13` is not included but in express edition is?

We are using `BETWEEN`

The column is `DATE`

Comment: This sounds pretty incredible, could you include the query you are using?

Comment: Could you include your select statement and the results you're getting?

Comment: This is the date search row: pr.LAST_CONFIRMED_1ST BETWEEN date '2016-07-11' and date '2016-07-13'

Comment: What is a type of `LAST_CONFIRMED_1ST` column? Is it a timestamp, date, timestamp with timezone? Is the type of column the same on both databases?

Comment: [edit] your question and add the `create table` statement for the table in question and the complete query you are using. If I had to guess: the two installations are using different NLS settings and you are subject to the evil implicit data type conversion problems.

Comment: What is the **exact** query you use?

Comment: we used pr.LAST_CONFIRMED_1ST >= '2016-07-11 00:00:00.0'
AND pr.LAST_CONFIRMED_1ST <= '2016-07-13 00:00:00.0',
now we added to_timestamp(pr.LAST_CONFIRMED_1ST)